# Auto adjusting navigation menu

Tags: css

I want to create a navigation menu that auto adjusts it's *width* depending on the amount of content (Buttons) within the menu.

**For example:**

Navigation menu will have 4 buttons within; each button having a `'min-width:25px'` and a `max-'width:100px'` depending on the text within.

So if all 4 buttons had the same amount of text within and were all equal to `50px`, the nav-menu DIV that holds all the buttons within it should automatically adjust to `200px`. If I then add a 5th button that has a width of `65px`, the nav-menu DIV should auto adjust to `265px`.

**The Problem**

My buttons work (they auto adjust the width depending on the amount of text within), however, my nav menu (nav-top) does not auto adjust. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm guessing that it is a simple fix.

**My HTML for the DIV and all the buttons:**

```
   <div id="nav-top" >

    <ul class="top-nav">
     <li><a href="">Home </a></li>
     <li><a href="">About Us </a></li>
     <li><a href="">Apply </a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
    </ul>

   </div><!--nav-top-->
```

**My CSS:**

```
/* Holds all the buttons */
#nav-top {
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:900px;
    height:35px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#555;
    top:7px;

}


.top-nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align:left;

}


.top-nav a {
   display: block;
   background-color: #888;
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   min-width:25px;
   max-width:100px;
   float:left;
   padding:7px;

}

.top-nav a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I recommend removing the spaces after each option; it's much easier to get that effect in one CSS line instead of remembering to include it after every option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a table layout style would work here. An element with `display:table` will flex to fit its children `table-cell`s.

```
ul.top-nav{    
    display:table;
    max-width:900px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul.top-nav li {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

See my [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9wWk/)

Answer (score 0):

how about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/LC46X/) and next time always use fiddle for this much code

I've made the `width` of outer div `100%` and the `li`'s are `25%` so that they all can fit

Comment: This assumes there will always be 4 menu items but the OP states that the menu should cope with adding a 5th button.

Comment: @moob you are right sir, I've ignored that.. the concept of display table cell is right :)

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed, but it's still helpful. Thank you.